# How to use @Inject?

Tags: java, spring

Earlier i had the implemenation like:

```
public class FeedbackService {
  private final FeedbackHelper feedbackHelper;

  @Inject
  public FeedbackService(FeedbackHelper feedbackHelper) {
    this.feedbackHelper = feedbackHelper;
  }
  //rest of the class
}
```

Test file

```
public class FeedbackDataServiceTest {
  private FeedbackService feedbackService;
  @Mock private FeedbackHelper feedbackHelper;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.feedbackService = new FeedbackService(feedbackHelper);
  }
}
```

It was workign fine. But when I changed to:

```
public class FeedbackService {
  @Inject private FeedbackHelper feedbackHelper;

}
```

Test file

```
public class FeedbackDataServiceTest {
  private FeedbackService feedbackService;
  @Mock private FeedbackHelper feedbackHelper;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }
}
```

The test cases started failing. Is anything else required to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@InjectMocks` to inject the mocks into the Service class.

```
public class FeedbackDataServiceTest {
  @InjectMocks private FeedbackService feedbackService;
  @Mock private FeedbackHelper feedbackHelper;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of injection. The suggestion is to use constructor injection if the dependency is mandatory and setter injection if it is optional.
You can use `@InjectMock` on the under test object if you want to mock a field injection. But it is hard to test if you want to test without mocking framework.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ApplicationTest 
{
    @InjectMocks
    MainClass sut;

    @Mock
    DatabaseDAO dependentClassOne;

    @Test
    public void validateTest()
    {
        boolean saved = sut.save("abcd");
        assertEquals(true, saved);
    }
```